# How to return an image through asmx web service and show in html page

Tags: html, web-services, url, return, asmx

I want to return image(s) through asmx webservice and show them in a html page.
I should not images are located in a folder named by numbers (1.jpg, 2.jpg and etc.) on server and also I should note that I don't want to make and use url for each image because it may cause security issues for me.

I have a textbox in my html page with a submit button and I want to see "1.jpg" in my html page when I insert 1 in textbox and press submit button.

Please help me to play out.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a textbox in my html page with a submit button and I want to see "1.jpg" in my html page when I insert 1 in textbox and press submit button.

Simply return the image data from your service along with the appropriate `Content-Type` header, such as `image/jpeg`.  Then, use JavaScript to create an `img` element that references your service:

```
<img src="images.asmx?image=1.jpg" />
```

> I don't want to make and use url for each image because it may cause security issues for me.

I don't know what security issues you're referring to, but just because you can access these images via script doesn't make them secure.  Anyone can access them this way unless you take steps to prevent it.  It's no different than simply changing the URL.

Comment: this the way that you perform this action or you have better idea?

Comment: also, can you give me complete code for service and javascript?